# How can I select a "section" of a path in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, selections, pen-tool

I am creating a series of trees in Photoshop, using paths. My plan is to complete the first tree, and then edit the same path for the other trees. I have already created 2 trees in this manner, but modifying the path is extremely tedious, mainly because there is no undo button for selections.

I am looking for a way to select "an entire branch" of the tree using only one selection. For example, if I have a path like this:

x----x----x----x

then I would like to select the first point and the last point, press some magical button, and have it select all the points in between.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are they actually **paths**? Drawn with the pen tool? If yes, use the Selection and Direct Selection Tools. If no.. use the Pen Tool.

Comment: @Scott Yes, they are actually paths. I drew them with the pen tool, and all of my paths show up in the "paths" menu instead of the "Layers" menu. So far I have been using the direct selection tool, but that requires me to select each point individually, or draw a box around the points. Both of these are somewhat tedious, and I'm wondering if I can select all of the points between 2 points. I can post screenshots if it is still unclear.

Comment: Path operations in Photoshop, especially anything before CS6, are pretty basic. There's not much you can do to improve working if you're stuck with Photoshop CS5. There's no way to select the point between two selected points other than the shift-click them. Using Illustrator would make it all much, much, easier if you know Illustrator.

Comment: I see. I do have Illustrator CS5, I might try using that (though I am not at all familiar with it). Thanks for the help! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it for you